# Analyse UDP delay from tcpdump files

Tags: networking, vlc-media-player, udp, tcpdump, delay

I have a video streamer (VLC) which is using RTP to stream video to a client. I have captured the packet trace from both the sender and the receiver side using `tcpdump` separately.

The streaming produces UDP packets. It is possible that some packets are missing/out of order on the receiver side. Assume that the clocks on both the machines are synchronized.

My task is to find the delay between the packets

*Q : Is there any tool which can compare both the dump files and generate UDP statistics, specifically delay?*

Comment: Any help? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it manually. I wrote a python script which

- extracts the packet from each pcap file (sender and receiver)
- compares their payload
- if it's a match and timestamps are causally correct, then delay is calculated
- If a match is not found over a certain window size (I kept it as 100), the packet is assumed to be lost and we move to the next packet

I did this over the entire pcap file and made an average over all the delays.
If somebody wants it, I can share the code.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) offers support for [RTP Analysis](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChTelRTPAnalysis.html).

See also these RTP-related Wireshark wiki pages: [RTP](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP), [RTP Statistics](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP_statistics).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if there is any change to filtering RTP headers in TCPDUMP.
When I have some files from TCPDUMP with a space bigger than my memory RAM can support, I can get delay, packet loss, and jitter.

Could you please provide some guidelines to do this to finish my report from my master's degree?

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185066)